# Replacing values based on one level value of multiindex in a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a multiindex. The levels are `gender`, `type` and lastly `age`. where I want to replace the value of one age with another within that group. So I'm guessing i need to use `.groupby()`.

Below I present an example of the problem, that I have.

This is the DataFrame I have initially:

```
Index    Gender    Type    Age    Value
0        'f'       'a'     0      'A1'
1        'f'       'a'     1      'A2'
2        'f'       'a'     2      'B1'
3        'f'       'a'     3      'xx'
4        'f'       'a'     4      'B5'
5        'f'       'a'     5      'F3'
6        'f'       'a'     6      'B6'
7        'f'       'a'     7      'Q10'
8        'f'       'a'     8      'A3'
9        'f'       'a'     9      'A1'
10       'f'       'b'     0      'D1'
11       'f'       'b'     1      'V2'
12       'f'       'b'     2      'V1'
13       'f'       'b'     3      'xx'
14       'f'       'b'     4      'G5'
15       'f'       'b'     5      'D3'
16       'f'       'b'     6      'B6'
17       'f'       'b'     7      'Q14'
18       'f'       'b'     8      'A3'
19       'm'       'a'     0      'A1'
20       'm'       'a'     1      'A2'
21       'm'       'a'     2      'B1'
21       'm'       'a'     3      'xx'
23       'm'       'a'     4      'B5'
24       'm'       'a'     5      'A3'
25       'm'       'a'     6      'B6'
26       'm'       'a'     7      'B15'
27       'm'       'a'     8      'A3'
28       'm'       'a'     9      'A1'
29       'm'       'b'     2      'V1'
30       'm'       'b'     3      'xx'
31       'm'       'b'     4      'R5'
32       'm'       'b'     5      'B3'
33       'm'       'b'     6      'W6'
34       'm'       'b'     7      'Q12'
```

As visible, each row for `age==3`, the value is `xx`.
I want that value replaced with the value of age 7 within each gender-type group.

That is:

```
Index    Gender    Type    Age    Value
0        'f'       'a'     0      'A1'
1        'f'       'a'     1      'A2'
2        'f'       'a'     2      'B1'
3        'f'       'a'     3      'Q10'
4        'f'       'a'     4      'B5'
5        'f'       'a'     5      'F3'
6        'f'       'a'     6      'B6'
7        'f'       'a'     7      'Q10'
8        'f'       'a'     8      'A3'
9        'f'       'a'     9      'A1'
10       'f'       'b'     0      'D1'
11       'f'       'b'     1      'V2'
12       'f'       'b'     2      'V1'
13       'f'       'b'     3      'Q14'
14       'f'       'b'     4      'G5'
15       'f'       'b'     5      'D3'
16       'f'       'b'     6      'B6'
17       'f'       'b'     7      'Q14'
18       'f'       'b'     8      'A3'
19       'm'       'a'     0      'A1'
20       'm'       'a'     1      'A2'
21       'm'       'a'     2      'B1'
21       'm'       'a'     3      'B15'
23       'm'       'a'     4      'B5'
24       'm'       'a'     5      'A3'
25       'm'       'a'     6      'B6'
26       'm'       'a'     7      'B15'
27       'm'       'a'     8      'A3'
28       'm'       'a'     9      'A1'
29       'm'       'b'     2      'V1'
30       'm'       'b'     3      'Q12'
31       'm'       'b'     4      'R5'
32       'm'       'b'     5      'B3'
33       'm'       'b'     6      'W6'
34       'm'       'b'     7      'Q12'
```

Notice, the DataFrame is not balanced, in the sense that the  range of ages within each gender-type group is not the same. It doesn't start and end at the same age, so as age 3 is not the same index within each group I can't use `iloc` but rather `loc` in some way.

Thanks for your help beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the custom function that will process each group individually:

```
def fix(g):
    g.loc[g['Age'] == 3, 'Value'] = g.loc[g['Age'] == 7, 'Value'].iloc[0]
    return g

df.groupby(['Gender', 'Type']).apply(fix)
```